# There are $10$ students and $16$ classes. What is the probability that at least two students will be selected in each class?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

> There are $10$ students and $16$ classes.  Those $10$ students will attend all of those $16$ classes.Teachers in each classes can select any student to ask question.  For example, the teacher in class $1$ can select no students or can also select $3$ students to ask question. This process will repeat in each classes.  Then, what is the probability that at least two students will be selected  in each class?

**My solution:** $$\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{16}(-1)^k\binom{16}{k}\bigg[\binom{10}{0}+\binom{10}{1}\bigg]^k\bigg[\binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{3}...+\binom{10}{10}\bigg]^{16-k}}{\bigg[\binom{10}{0}+\binom{10}{1}...+\binom{10}{10}\bigg]^{16}}$$

$$\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{16}(-1)^k\binom{16}{k}(11)^k(2^{10}-11)^{16-k}}{2^{160}}$$

**Am I right ?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does it mean that "each student can be selected at most once for each class"? I would think if one randomly puts each student in a class then it is impossible to put the same student in two or more classes. So I fail to see the need for the restriction.

Comment: @coffeemath assume that bob is one of the students, then bob cannot be selected more than once to solve a question.

Comment: @coffeemath but bob can be selected in other classes again

Comment: @coffeemath assume that teacher in first class asked $10$ question , bob can be selected at most once to solve question

Comment: the question is difficult to understand: It mentions "questions" but these did not get introduced, it seems to be missing interpunction and I am not sure how many classes each student takes.

Comment: @student91 read the question, again .I hope it will be understood now

Comment: @coffeemath read the question, again .I hope it will be understood now

Comment: It is still somewhat hard to see the set-up. Examples might help, some which are OK and some others not OK (and why not).

Comment: @coffeemath (and **To the Original Poster**): If I am not mistaken, the problem is ambiguous and requires additional information in order to be solvable.  The problem needs to specify either : [1] The probability that for example) a teacher selects student-1 to ask a question.  or [2] For $~k \in \{0,1,2\cdots,10\}, ~$ the probability that a teacher selects exactly $~k~$ students to ask questions.  The OP (i.e. original poster) seems to be assuming that the probability is exactly (1/2) that a teacher calls on a specific student.  ...see next comment

Comment: @coffeemath (and **To the Original Poster**): It is reasonable to assume that the probability of a teacher calling on one student is independent of whether the teacher calls on other students.  It is also reasonable to assume that the behavior of one teacher is independent of the behavior of any other teacher.  However, nowhere in the problem's premises does it specify that (for example) the probability of the teacher calling on any specific student is $~(1/2).~$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that in each class, the probability of $0$ or $1$ student being selected is the same probability $p$.
If I understand your problem statement correctly,
then the probability of at least $2$ students being selected in every class is simply $(1-p)^{16}$.

Since you did not specify any information that allows us to determine $p$,
there is no unique answer.
However, if we assume that in each class,
each student has $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of being selected,
then $p=(\frac{1}{2})^{10}+10\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^{10}$.
The final answer would be $(\frac{1013}{1024})^{16}$.

I don't see why you would apply the inclusion-exclusion principle.
I assume it has to do with the unspecified mechanism of determining $p$.